# Strange gap between container and internal div

Tags: css, html

I'm building a game page and I'd like to put a top information bar inside a larger container that will hold the full game window. Right now there is a gap between the border of the game window and the green background of the info bar, and I'd like it to be at the very top.

HTML

```
<div class = "game-window">

    <div class ="info-bar">
        <p id="messageline">New Game!</p>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success" id="newpickbutton" onclick="buypick()">Buy a new pick!</button>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="digbutton" onclick="dig()">Dig!</button>

</div>
```

CSS

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Layout
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    .game-window {
        border: solid 3px;
        width:800px;
        height: 800px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }

    .info-bar {
        border: solid 0px transparent;
        background-color:lightgreen;
        height:100px;
    }

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Screen Elements
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #digbutton {
        width:500px; 
        height:500px;
    }

    #messageline {
        margin-top:20px;
    }
```

If I remove the line `border: solid 3px;` from the game-window class, the info-bar positions itself properly, but I can't figure out how to keep the border and have the info-bar at the top (but still inside the border).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the margin on your messageline paragraph.

```
#messageline {
    margin:0px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qjt3u/)**

Comment: Oh, I feel a bit silly now. I had forgotten why I needed that margin - it was from a past layout and I guess I didn't. Thanks!

Comment: Or you can add `overflow:auto` to your `.info-bar` div. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jc6Dw/

Answer (score 1):

Related to what j08691 said - if you want that margin, you can add any kind of padding to the parent element - `.info-bar` in this case, the margin will only 'push' against the parent. One of those weird things about CSS.

```
.info-bar {
    border: solid 0px transparent;
    background-color:lightgreen;
    height:100px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
```

[See this codepen for an example.](http://codepen.io/chippper/pen/HKIsx/)